# What syntax should I use to update a record written in C#.net with Oracle Database

Tags: c#, oracle

I am a beginner and facing a problem while updating a record stored in Oracle Database and written in `C# .NET`. The connection is successful, insert and delete query works properly. Please suggest me what should i do.

My code is:

```
private void btnUpadate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection con = null;
    try
    {
        con = new OracleConnection();
        string constr = "Data source=XE; User ID=cloudester; Password=cloudester123;";

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                con.ConnectionString = constr;
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Caught");
            }
        }
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Update EMP_DETAIL set Name= :Name, Age=:Age where EmpId=:EmpId";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EmpId", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtEmpId.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Age", OracleDbType.Int16)).Value = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    finally
    {
        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happen when your code is executing? Exception?

Comment: No it do not throw any exception, it just executes with no update to db

Comment: As an aside, use the `using` statement to ensure that it gets closed properly even on error instead of that construct with `con.State != ConnectionState.Open`.

Comment: Have you used the debugger, what does `i.ToString()` return, `"0"`? Is `EmpId` really a string or an int?

Comment: Yes i.ToString() returns "0" and i have use debugger but no error occured there as well

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? `cmd.BindByName = true`

Comment: Yes but it also do not work

Comment: Ok. When filling the collection parameters specify the parameter name followed by a colon. (":EmpId" instead "EmpId", ":Name" instead "Name" ...)

Answer (score 1):

You should assign True to cmd.BindByName property before call ExecuteNonQuery or fill parameters collection in right order (as parameters appear in sql command text)

Comment: Thanks Sohaty i have tried one and now it works. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

There may be two reasons for 'executes with no update to db'.

1. Don't forget to do COMMIT. Until commit, changes are not visible to outside sessions. Session can use auto-commit or something else but.. force it.
2. UPDATE statement can update 0 records if where clause is wrong i.e. it just cannot find the record specified. Usually you can check 'records affected' counter (I guess it's a result of ExecuteNonQuery)

Comment: Please tell me how i can COMMIT. What syntax i should use??

Comment: Yes, `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected rows. All commands are implicitly committed unless you call `BeginTransaction()` method before. As far as I know there is no "auto-commit" property available on ODP.NET connection.